# Calculate Time To Decimal in Google Sheets

Tags: time, google-sheets, format, decimal

How can I calculate time to decimal in Google sheets using a formula?

Basically, I have something like this set up:

```
Gross Pay: 16.63
Total Online: 1.53 (Represents 1 hour 53 minutes)
Hourly Rate: 10.87 (Just a formula that divides gross pay from total online)
```

Which is incorrect because 1 hour 53 minutes is 1.88 hours.

I need my hourly rate cell to have 16.63 / 1.88 to get the correct result. Anybody know any formula to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Please try:

```
=int(A1)+(mod(A1,1)/0.6)
```

to return `1.88` from `1.53` in Cell A1.

Splits `1.53` at the decimal, removes the decimal ("x100") and divides the minutes by 60, to get their proportion of one hour.